# I need to add all my output numbers from my loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i enter in a word e.g. "quiz" i get the output:

```
10
1
1
10
```

When i want:

```
22 (Adds all the numbers)
```

My workaround:

```
SCORES = {
  'a' : 1, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 3 , 'd' : 2, 'e' : 1, 'f' : 4, 'g' : 2,
  'h' : 4, 'i' : 1, 'j' : 8 , 'k' : 5, 'l' : 1, 'm' : 3, 'n' : 1,
  'o' : 1, 'p' : 3, 'q' : 10, 'r' : 1, 's' : 1, 't' : 1, 'u' : 1,
  'v' : 4, 'w' : 4, 'x' : 8 , 'y' : 4, 'z' : 10,
}
a = input("Enter word: ")
for b in a:
  c = SCORES[b]
  print(c)
```

Please help! :)

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting it? :( Please i need help :(

Comment: I imagine that the downvotes are because you say you need to add the numbers, but nowhere in the code is the addition operator (`+`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not summing the values. You can modify your code as follows:

```
a = input("Enter word: ")
a = a.strip()
total = 0
for b in a:
  c = SCORES[b]
  total += c
print total
```

Alternately, you could use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and list comprehension:

```
>>> SCORES = {
...   'a' : 1, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 3 , 'd' : 2, 'e' : 1, 'f' : 4, 'g' : 2,
...   'h' : 4, 'i' : 1, 'j' : 8 , 'k' : 5, 'l' : 1, 'm' : 3, 'n' : 1,
...   'o' : 1, 'p' : 3, 'q' : 10, 'r' : 1, 's' : 1, 't' : 1, 'u' : 1,
...   'v' : 4, 'w' : 4, 'x' : 8 , 'y' : 4, 'z' : 10,
... }
>>> word = 'quiz'
>>> sum([SCORES.get(a.lower()) for a in word])
22
```